# flutter why can't I print device's location on screen

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I was trying to print my emulated device's location but it just prints a bunch of stuff rather than the location of the device. I've checked and the device's location is turned on.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(LocationApp());
}

class LocationApp extends StatelessWidget {
  void locationGet() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
    print(position);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              locationGet();
            },
            child: Text('LOCATION'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is what I'm getting as an error while the location of the device is turned on and I have even allowed the use of location when it prompted me

```
E/flutter ( 7183): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: The location service on the device is disabled.
E/flutter ( 7183): #0      MethodChannelGeolocator._handlePlatformException (package:geolocator_platform_interface/src/implementations/method_channel_geolocator.dart:173:9)
E/flutter ( 7183): #1      MethodChannelGeolocator.getPositionStream.<anonymous closure> (package:geolocator_platform_interface/src/implementations/method_channel_geolocator.dart:152:11)
E/flutter ( 7183): #2      _invokeErrorHandler (dart:async/async_error.dart:16:24)
E/flutter ( 7183): #3      _HandleErrorStream._handleError (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:282:9)
E/flutter ( 7183): #4      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleError (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:161:13)
E/flutter ( 7183): #5      _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1214:47)
E/flutter ( 7183): #6      _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1107:19)
E/flutter ( 7183): #7      _CustomZone.runBinaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1013:7)
E/flutter ( 7183): #8      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError.sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:376:15)
E/flutter ( 7183): #9      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:394:16)
E/flutter ( 7183): #10     _BufferingStreamSubscription._addError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:294:7)
E/flutter ( 7183): #11     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._addError (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:132:11)
E/flutter ( 7183): #12     _ForwardingStream._handleError (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:97:10)
E/flutter ( 7183): #13     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleError (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:161:13)
E/flutter ( 7183): #14     _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1214:47)
E/flutter ( 7183): #15     _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1107:19)
E/flutter ( 7183): #16     _CustomZone.runBinaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1013:7)
E/flutter ( 7183): #17     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError.sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:376:15)
E/flutter ( 7183): #18     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:394:16)
E/flutter ( 7183): #19     _DelayedError.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:622:14)
E/flutter ( 7183): #20     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:730:11)
E/flutter ( 7183): #21     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:687:7)
E/flutter ( 7183): #22     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1182:47)
E/flutter ( 7183): #23     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter ( 7183): #24     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
E/flutter ( 7183): #25     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
E/flutter ( 7183): #26     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
E/flutter ( 7183): #27     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter ( 7183): #28     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
E/flutter ( 7183): #29     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
E/flutter ( 7183): #30     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
E/flutter ( 7183): #31     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
E/flutter ( 7183): 
D/EGL_emulation( 7183): eglMakeCurrent: 0xd921a120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd920f1e0)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question with the results of flutter doctor --verbose and flutter run --verbose?

Comment: Are you sure you have accepted permission? `The following message is displayed if the user declined to accept the permissions when getCurrentPosition() is called.`

Comment: @Nuts I have a same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that some of the android virtual device's in android studio have bugs, in this case it was the google pixel 3, no matter what you do it will not return its location, you can fix it by just using a different device, the Nexus 5x works fine.

Comment: @user8240155 Your suggestion cannot solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

you could try asking for permission:

```
LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
```

Got it from here:
https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator

Also, in order to print the location, you should print something like this:

```
print(position == null ? 'Unknown' : position.latitude.toString() + ', ' + position.longitude.toString());
});
```

Comment: I am getting the same result

Comment: In an app of mine i get location like this:

import 'package:location/location.dart';

 getLocation() async {
    debugPrint("Entramos en la selección de localización");
    LocationData currentLocation;
    var location = new Location();
    debugPrint("Se crea el objeto localización");
    currentLocation = await location.getLocation();
}

You could try it out

Answer (score 0):

- When you're using geolocator on a emulator, you always get the same position (37.4219983, -122.084). That's the default settings.
- On a real device, I think there is actually a problem with the package on some android versions. I am getting the same error ("The location service on the device is disabled."). The issue has been reported on the github repository [issue 585](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/585) . Some solutions has been proposed, like trying with different desiredAccuracy (best, high, medium).